# Weird safari CSS Jquery bug

Tags: jquery, css, safari

Hi i have some weird bug im my page. Hope some one can help. Because im getting way to grey heird to early.

On safari (as far as can tell), my page is loading in a weird way. Is like the hole page i loading in from the top left corner, and the spreading out onto the page.

Can't see what css or jquery should have done that. But it's messing white my packery plugin when it does.

It's only when enter the site not when you refresh the site.

can some help and see whats going on.

my dev link is: http://deploy.medieskyen.dk/bymem/

Comment: Not seeing anything unusual on my end.

Comment: But is the images sitting belowe each orther or "packed"

Comment: I'm on Safari OSX, and Firefox OSX. Both pages are displaying the same for me. Take a screenshot of what your seeing.

Comment: I can't take a screen because It's happing fast. But all the elements is cramp up into to the left top corner. And the animates Them self out into place.  But when they does the packery plugin dosnt work a alle images are belowe each other instead of packed in place.

Comment: Well asswipe english is not first language and on top of that im dyslexic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the problem.

I had transition: all on all of my wrappers, and aparently safari translate this to i should animate to wrappers to is correct size.